# Нужно у стороны куба увеличить ширину и высоту, а потом уменьшить

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Задача: есть такой вот куб

```
<nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a class="link1" href="#side1">Сторона 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="link2" href="#side2">Сторона 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="link3" href="#side3">Сторона 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="link4" href="#side4">Сторона 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="link5" href="#side5">Сторона 5</a></li>
    <li><a class="link6" href="#side6">Сторона 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main-cube">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side" id="side1">1</div>
    <div class="side" id="side2">2</div>
    <div class="side" id="side3">3</div>
    <div class="side" id="side4">4</div>
    <div class="side" id="side5">5</div>
    <div class="side" id="side6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(".link1").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg)");
});

$(".link2").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,270deg)");
});

$(".link3").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)");
});

$(".link4").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(1,0,0,270deg)");
});

$(".link5").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg)");
});

$(".link6").click(function() {
  $('.cube').css("transform", "rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg)");
});
</script>
```

Нужно чтобы у него увеличивалась лицевая сторона (класс `side`), таких сторон шесть, и нужно чтобы увеличивалась лишь та, на которую мы смотрим, а когда нажмем на ссылку, чтобы эта сторона возвращала исходные размеры, куб разворачивается и опять та другая лицевая сторона увеличивает значения `width` и `height` до значений `90vw` и `90vh` соответственно.

Опишу еще проще: если `.side = rotateY(90deg)` то увеличиваем размеры этой стороны `width = 90vw`, `height = 90vh`. Причем чтобы это происходило через `setTimeOut`. То есть кубик повернулся, увеличился ширина потом высота, если нажали другую сторону, то ширина и высота сжались до дефолтных значений (`600х600 pixel`), кубик повернулся и снова та другая сторона увеличилась до значений `width = 90vw`, height = 90vh.

Все перегуглил переяндексил нет ответа. Может намётку хоть какую дадите?

Answer (score 0):

Создаете класс:

```
.active.side{
    width:90vw;
    height:90vw;
    transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
    // 1s - длительность анимации
    // 0.5s - задержка
}
```

Если обратно хотим убирать размер без задержки

```
.side{
    transition-delay: 0;
}
```

Нужный класс добаляем при нажатии на пункт меню:

```
var side=$('.cube .side').eq(1) //1 - нужная сторона куба
side.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
```